# Hi I am a beginner to Java. I encountered a problem when trying to catch InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Hi I am a beginner to Java. I have created a problem that is able to define the age group of the person who enters any number of their age using the if and else if statements, but with the prerequisite that the date input can be nothing but numbers. In order to achieve this condition, I tried to try and catch InputMismatchException. Nevertheless, I encountered a problem when trying to catch InputMatchException.
What I wished to accomplish is, when data input is anything other than numbers, for the following program to display the error message once only:"Input error. Please enter a number corresponding to your age."
However both this error message written by myself and the following error occurred when test running the program.

```
 "Input error. Please enter the number corresponding to your age.
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
        at Welcome.main(Welcome.java:11)"
```

I also tried to use the throw new InputMismatchException but it failed to work. I do not understand the concept throw new Exception well. Please help me achieve the condition above. thank you!

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your age and we will define your age group.");
        double age;
        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                age = input.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Input error. Please enter a number corresponding to your age.");
            }
            age = input.nextDouble();
            if (age <= -1)
                System.out.println("It is impossible for negative values to hold true.");
            else if (age <= 0.1)
                System.out.println("You are a newborn.");
            else if (age <= 1)
                System.out.println("You are an infant.");
            else if (age <= 3)
                System.out.println("You are a toddler.");
            else if (age <= 5)
                System.out.println("You are a preschooler.");
            else if (age <= 13)
                System.out.println("You are a school-aged child.");
            else if (age <= 19)
                System.out.println("You are an adolescent and a denarian.");
            else if (age <= 29)
                System.out.println("You are a vicenarian.");
            else if (age <= 39)
                System.out.println("You are a tricenarian.");
            else if (age <= 49)
                System.out.println("You are a quadragenarian.");
            else if (age <= 59)
                System.out.println("You are a quinquagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 69)
                System.out.println("You are a sexagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 79)
                System.out.println("You are a septuagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 89)
                System.out.println("You are an octogenarian.");
            else if (age <= 99)
                System.out.println("You are a nonagenarian.");
            else if (age <= 109)
                System.out.println("You are a centenarian.");
            else if (age <= 150)
                System.out.println("You are a supercentenarian.");
            else if (age >= 150)
                System.out.println("This value is too big to hold true.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Below your try/catch, you have another line with `age=input.nextDouble();`. I guess that's where the stacktrace comes from.

Comment: Your exception handling isn't going to work. You're going to be prompted twice (the second time without a message to the user) if the user *does* get the input right and if the user gets it wrong there won't be a second opportunity to try

Comment: There is no such thing as `InputMatchException`.

Comment: Please look up and try to follow Java code formatting rules. By following these rules, others will more easily be able to read and understand your code, and then be able to help you. If you are using most IDE's they can help you format your code correctly for you.

Comment: Hi, f1sh, I agree with you, but the other line was added as an attempt to make the syntax correct. Hi, g00se, thank you for your comment. Could you please provide a solution to this problem? Hi, user207421, it's not InputMatchException but InputMismatchException. InputMismatchException has to be imported first before being used.

Comment: Place the prompt string into the `while` loop so that when it re-loops the prompt is shown again. Add this: `input.nextLine();` (to consume the ENTER hit) and this: `continue;` directly under the error message in the `catch` block. Get rid of that other `age = input.nextDouble();` line that is directly **under** the `catch` block. Consider adding a **Quit** mechanism to exit the loop, perhaps something like: `if (age < 0.0d) { break; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the a `double` value twice and only once you account for a possible type mismatch. So remove that second `input.nextDouble()`.

You should also use [`continue;`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp) when the exception is thrown so the current iteration is stopped immediately and continues with the next iteration meaning your program will give the user another chance to enter an age. Additionally you should move the `System.out.println("Please enter...")` within the loop so a user knows what to do.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double age;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your age and we will define your age group.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            age = input.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Input error. Please enter a number corresponding to your age.");
            continue;
        }
        // if you use double you need to use another condition as age -0.1 would leave a "hole" in your ifs
        // < 0
        if (age <= -1) System.out.println("It is impossible for negative values to hold true.");
        else if (age <= 0.1) System.out.println("You are a newborn.");
        else if (age <= 1) System.out.println("You are an infant.");
        else if (age <= 3) System.out.println("You are a toddler.");
        else if (age <= 5) System.out.println("You are a preschooler.");
        else if (age <= 13) System.out.println("You are a school-aged child.");
        else if (age <= 19) System.out.println("You are an adolescent and a denarian.");
        else if (age <= 29) System.out.println("You are a vicenarian.");
        else if (age <= 39) System.out.println("You are a tricenarian.");
        else if (age <= 49) System.out.println("You are a quadragenarian.");
        else if (age <= 59) System.out.println("You are a quinquagenarian.");
        else if (age <= 69) System.out.println("You are a sexagenarian.");
        else if (age <= 79) System.out.println("You are a septuagenarian.");
        else if (age <= 89) System.out.println("You are an octogenarian.");
        else if (age <= 99) System.out.println("You are a nonagenarian.");
        else if (age <= 109) System.out.println("You are a centenarian.");
        else if (age <= 150) System.out.println("You are a supercentenarian.");
        // age can`t be <= 150 at this point (when you correct your bug above), so no need for this condition
        else if (age >= 150) System.out.println("This value is too big to hold true.");
    }
}
```

Some remarks on your code:

- Age usually is an `int` but if you want it to be a `double` (which is fine as well, just uncommon) you need to adjust your condition `<= -1` for negative values, otherwise you will get unexpected results for example for an age of `-0.1`.
- Your last `else if` also does not make much sense. You could just use `else` here.
- You should also consider to catch the other exceptions that can happen when using a scanner, not just `TypeMismatchException`.
- Maybe also provide a way for a user to exit the program as it currently runs in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and the correct code that you have provided!

Comment: Thank you. Still with an `int` your `switch` statement would need 151 cases plus a default case. It would work if you want it. (Could also consider a `Map<Integer, String>` with 151 entries.)

Comment: Hi. By the way, would you mind illustrating more examples of the keyword 'continue'? Since I am a beginner, I am not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: @Alanzhou I am sure your search engine will be helpful.